# Как разбить строку на 2 строки учитывая регистр?

Tags: xcode, swift

Как разбить строку "BlueCar" на 2 строки - "Blue" и "Car"?

Есть строка, написанная слитно. Нужно разбить строку на 2 строки по регистру буквы. Если следующая буква заглавная - значит она и все что за ней будет новая строка.

Возможно это можно сделать через стандартные свойства, но я не могу найти как. Через массив, также не получается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import Foundation

var string = "BlueCar"
var regexp: NSRegularExpression = try NSRegularExpression.init(pattern: "([a-z])([A-Z])", options: [])
let range = NSMakeRange(0, string.characters.count)
let newString = regexp.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(string, options: [], range: range, withTemplate: "$1 $2")
let array: Array = newString.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
```